# ScaledRelativeLayout wrong scale with the onDraw method

Tags: android, canvas, android-custom-view, ondraw

I succeed to create a ViewPager with items which a different scale (the currentItem have a scale like 1.0f and the others 0.85f). I use this custom layout :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class ScaledRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    private float scale = MainActivity.BIG_SCALE;

    public ScaledRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScaledRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setScaleBoth(float scale) {
        this.scale = scale;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.scale(scale, scale, getWidth() / 2, getHeight()/2);
    }
}
```

The thing is it's working, on my Nexus 7 (2012) but not on my smartphone and I can't figure why... I was thinking maybe I make a bad scale in the onDraw method after some search, I try this :

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(scale, scale, getWidth() / 2, getHeight()/2);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Nothing worked, any idea ?

Comment: maybe you should onMeasure to decide the size of your RelativLayout.

Comment: `canvas.scale` at the end of `onDraw` makes little sense

Comment: I tried both, but yes you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeed to scale my layout by extending FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout and I don't know... If someone can explain why it's working with a FrameLayout but not with a RelativeLayout...